# Increase efficiency of name and data node in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, namenode, datanode

i have 1 name node and 2 data node with 32 gb ram in HDFS. But it is not taking more than 30 people at a time.Is there a way to improve the efficiency of name and data node

Comment: Are you actively monitoring JMX values? Just because you have so much RAM doesn't mean your Java processes actually use it. Datanode doesn't require much RAM anyway

Comment: You can improve HDFS significantly by lowering your overall file counts. Don't store millions of tiny files; store tens of gigantic files